# Mockito - Zero interactions with mock - Singleton

Tags: java, unit-testing, singleton, mockito

### **Preconditions**

I have the following class (fictional, just for demonstrating the problem):

```
public class MySingleton {

  private static MySingleton sMySingleton;
  private static List<String> sItemList;

  private MySingleton(List<String> list) {
      sItemList = list;
  }

  public static MySingleton getInstance(List<String> list) {
      if (sMySingleton == null) {
          sMySingleton = new MySingleton(list);
      }
      return sMySingleton;
  }

  public void addItem(String item) {
      sItemList.add(item);
  }

  public void removeItem(String item) {
      sItemList.remove(item);
  }
}
```

And an according test class:

```
public class MySingletonTest {

  private MySingleton mInstance;
  private List<String> mList;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
      mList = mock(List.class);
      mInstance = MySingleton.getInstance(mList);
  }

  @Test
  public void testAddItem() throws Exception {
      String item = "Add";
      mInstance.addItem(item);
      verify(mList, times(1)).add(item);
  }

  @Test
  public void testRemoveItem() throws Exception {
      String item = "Remove";
      mInstance.removeItem(item);
      verify(mList, times(1)).remove(item);
  }
}
```

---

### **Problem**

If I now execute the complete test class, Mockito tells me for the test `testRemoveItem()` that there were 0 interactions with the mock.

How is that possible?

---

**Note:**
Please do not start of a discussion about the sense singletons.
This question is about Mockito and why its not working.

Comment: I never used `mockito` but as I know in Unitests each `@Test` method starts from scratch. I think you need to add one item before remove it inside `testRemoveItem` test

Comment: Even if I do not add an item, at least the method should be called and recognized using the `verify`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JUnit creates a new test class instance for every single test, which Mockito populates with a new mock instance for every single test. However, your singleton only ever initializes itself once, meaning that `mList == MySingleton.sItemList` during the first test but `mList != MySingleton.sItemList` for every test after that.

In other words, the interaction is happening, but by the second test, you're checking the wrong mock.

Though I know you're not here to debate the merits of this type of singleton, bear in mind that you might have a hard time replacing the instance in tests if you do it this way. Instead, consider making the singleton's constructor available (only) to your tests, and keeping the `List` (or other state) within the instance. That way you can create a brand new "Singleton" for every individual test.

Comment: This sound resonable. It means a protected or package local constructor and removing the static modifier from the list member variable?

Comment: Ok, did a quick test, the list can be kept static, just changing the constructor to protected, making the class final and instantiating it this way inside the setup method gives the expected result. Thank you!

Comment: Yes. As long as `addItem` and `removeItem` are instance methods, they should probably interact with instance state, even if you're trying to guarantee in production that there will only ever be one instance. If you want `sItemList` to be static, there's no need to make the class instantiable at all.

Comment: @JDC Singletons make all the code using it basically impossible to test. And yours is even worse because it has a design problem: the second caller trying to get an instance with its own list is simply ignored, making the design even more questionable. You should really consider avoiding the singleton anti-pattern, and embrace dependency injection instead (which allows having singletons, but making the code using them very testable).

Comment: You are right, it does not make any sense to have the list inside as static, I have overseen this. And indeed, this makes the whole design questionable, as, like you correctly mentioned, the second caller will not get the class with his list, as the singleton has already been instantiated. This is actually a point I really completely did not see at first sight. Thank you very much!